# C# Newbie (extremely simple) how to store user input in a field and invoke a method to display the field value

Tags: c#, console-application

As an exercise, I want my console app to let me specify the value of a field, then use a method I made to display the field.  The method is supposed to display the value I entered.  Instead, it displays a blank line.

Program.cs

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Employee myEmployee = new Employee();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Position name:");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            myEmployee.Position = input;

            myEmployee.DisplayEmployeeInfo();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Employee.cs

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    class Employee
    {
        public string Position;

        public void DisplayEmployeeInfo()
        {
            Employee newEmployee = new Employee();
            Console.WriteLine(newEmployee.Position);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, is it common practice to reuse instantiated object names?

For example, felt like I needed to use  "myEmployee" in Program.cs and "newEmployee" in Employee.cs (even though they are in different contexts and, I could reuse the same name).  I'm just not sure what the best practice would be in this case.

Comment: Re: best practices. As long as it doesn't cause confusion that should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you instanciate a new `Employee` object in your `DisplayEmployeeInfo` method.

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    class Employee
    {
        public string Position;

        public void DisplayEmployeeInfo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Position);
        }
    }
}
```

It should do the trick.

For the naming part, I don't think there is really a best practice, usually you should try to follow the existing conventions of your project.

Comment: Thanks both answers are perfect.  However, this answer also answered my secondary sub-question as well.  Thank you.